# Nominativ oder Akkusativ?

Tags: grammatical-case, adverbial

In welchem Fall steht hier »das letzte Mal«? Im Nominativ oder Akkusativ? Und wie findet man das heraus?

> Wann warst du *das letzte Mal* bei Oma?

Comment: *Wann warst du d**en** letzte**n** Monat bei Oma?*

Comment: Akkusativ - Bau die Antwort, dann is der Fall klar (versuche, keine Präposition zu verwenden, die einen bestimmten Fall fordert): "letzten Monat", "letztes Jahr"

Answer (score 2):

Akkusativ. Man muss hier die Phrase als Satzteil identifizieren und wissen, welchen Kasus der Satzteil haben kann.

Im Beispielsatz "Wann warst du das letzte Mal bei Oma?" hat die Nominalphrase "das letzte Mal" als Satzteil die Funktion einer **adverbialen Bestimmung**, kurz **Adverbial** genannt. Dieses Adverbial unterscheidet sich von dem Adverbial "bei Oma" darin, dass es keine Präposition enthält. (Die Präposition "bei" in "bei Oma" bestimmt den Kasus Dativ.)

Die Regel ist nun, dass solche als Adverbiale dienende Nominalphrasen, die keine  Präposition enthalten, *entweder* im Akkusativ *oder* im Genitiv stehen (Stichwort: Adverbialakkusativ bzw. Adverbialgenitiv). Daher kann "das letzte Mal" in diesem Satz nicht im Nominativ stehen, und auch nicht im Dativ.

`Wann warst du { das letzte Mal }ᴬᴷᴷ { bei Oma }ᴰᴬᵀ ?`

Die Phrase kann nur dann im Nominativ stehen, wenn sie das **Subjekt** des Satzes ist oder wenn sie als **Prädikativ** mit einem Kopulaverb (sein, werden, bleiben) steht.

Als Subjekt:
 `{ Das letzte Mal }ᴺᴼᴹ war am schönsten.`
 
Wer/was war am schönsten? → Das letzte Mal.

Als Prädikativ, hier: Gleichsetzungsnominativ:
 `Das war { das letzte Mal }ᴺᴼᴹ !`
Wer/was war das? → Das letzte Mal.

Answer (score 1):

1. In welchem Fall steht hier »das letzte Mal«? Im Nominativ oder Akkusativ?
   **Akkusativ**
2. Wie findet man das heraus?

   Setze einfach etwas anderes ein, das den Original syntaktisch ähnlich ist, aber einen Unterschied zwischen Nominativ und Akkusativ zeigt. Zum Beispiel:

   - Nominativ:

     > *(Das ist)* das letze Mal.
     >   *(Das ist)* der letzte Monat.
   - Akkusativ:

     > *(Ich untersuche)* das letzte Mal.
     >   *(Ich untersuche)* den letzten Monat.

   Und dann setze ein:

   > Wann warst du *der letzte Monat* bei Oma? - wohl eher nicht
   >   Wann warst du *den letzten Monat* bei Oma? - das passt!

---

Anmerkung:

Das Wort »*Monat*« wird in österreichischem Deutsch bevorzugt als sächliches Substantiv verwendet (»*das* Monat«) (die männliche Form existiert in Ö aber ebenfalls). Nur hast du dann dasselbe Problem wie beim ebenfalls sächlichen Wort »*Mal*«: Akkusativ und Nominativ sind gleich (»Wann warst du *das letzte Monat* bei Oma?«)

Auch »die letzte Woche« eignet sich aus demselben Grund nicht.